# Android - Fail to get respond from server

Tags: android, httpresponse

This is my first time connecting to a server. I am trying to store values from android application into MySQL running in my server. However I am having problems connecting to my server. It is showing "Target server failed to respond" What could be the problem? And solutions?

.java class

```
public void sendRegistrationIdToServer(String deviceId,
        String registrationId) {
    Log.d("C2DM", "Sending registration ID to my application server");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.28.68.28/test.php?");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        // Get the deviceID
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceid", deviceId));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registrationid",
                registrationId));
        //HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(client.getParams(), false);
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("HTTP Status = "+status);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("HttpResponse", line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
12-30 11:35:43.494: WARN/System.err(771): org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
12-30 11:35:43.504: WARN/System.err(771):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:85)
12-30 11:35:43.504: WARN/System.err(771):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
12-30 11:35:43.514: WARN/System.err(771):     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
12-30 11:35:43.514: WARN/System.err(771):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
12-30 11:35:43.514: WARN/System.err(771):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
12-30 11:35:43.514: WARN/System.err(771):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
12-30 11:35:43.514: WARN/System.err(771):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
12-30 11:35:43.524: WARN/System.err(771):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:410)
12-30 11:35:43.524: WARN/System.err(771):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-30 11:35:43.524: WARN/System.err(771):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-30 11:35:43.524: WARN/System.err(771):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-30 11:35:43.524: WARN/System.err(771):     at de.vogella.android.c2dm.simpleclient.C2DMReceiverReceiver.sendRegistrationIdToServer(C2DMReceiverReceiver.java:121)
12-30 11:35:43.535: WARN/System.err(771):     at de.vogella.android.c2dm.simpleclient.C2DMReceiverReceiver.onReceive(C2DMReceiverReceiver.java:56)
12-30 11:35:43.535: WARN/System.err(771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1769)
12-30 11:35:43.535: WARN/System.err(771):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-30 11:35:43.544: WARN/System.err(771):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:978)
12-30 11:35:43.553: WARN/System.err(771):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

Comment: Have you verified that the request is reaching the server? Check logs on the server? Can you use something like `curl` successfully?

Comment: Are you sure the target is up and has an HTTP listener?

Comment: hmmm I realised I don't have any of those. Sorry, mind if I ask another question? How do I set up this listener? And yes, I'm able to use curl in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not getting any response from the server. Firstly, are you returning any values or response from your server? Do you have a server running? If not, you might want to take a look at XAMPP. It contains all your needs.